# use gensim with a pyarrow iterable

Tags: python, gensim, pyarrow

Consider this code

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile('/mybigparquet.pq')
for i in parquet_file.iter_batches(batch_size=100):
    print("training on batch")
    batch =  i.to_pandas()
  
    model = Word2Vec(sentences= batch.tokens, vector_size=100, window=5, workers=40, min_count = 10,epochs = 10)
```

As you can see, I am trying to train a `word2vec` model using a very large parquet file that does not fit entirely into my RAM. I know that `gensim` can operate on iterables (not generators, as the data need to be scanned twice in word2vec) and I know that `pyarrow` allows me to generate batches (of even one row) from the file.

Yet, this code is not working correctly. I think I need to write my `pyarrow` loop as a proper generator but I do not know how to do this.

What do you think?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new model every iteration of your loop, so at best, you'd only have, at the end, a single `model` from the last iteration – probably not what you want.

Instead, you need to give `Word2Vec` the kind of re-iterable Python sequence that it wants, where each item is a Python list of string word tokens.

Unless there's something in `pyarrow`/etc, this likely means your own class, that implements the Python 'iterable' interface, so that each time an *iterator* is requested from it, it starts a new iteration. Here's a [reasonable article section about how iterables work](https://realpython.com/python-iterators-iterables/#the-iterable-protocol). You'd be likely to make use of the generator pattern to achieve this, as mentioned [later in the same article](https://realpython.com/python-iterators-iterables/#exploring-alternative-ways-to-write-__iter__-in-iterables).

(Essentially: your `__iter__()` special function will start the iteration, and loop over the batches, always using `yield` to return the single next item. If you class is specialized for use as a Gensim `Word2Vec` corpus, each item yielded should be a Python `list` with string tokens.)

If you're really only using one column named 'tokens', no need to convert things through a Pandas `DataFrame` - that's just extra conversion/storage overhead. Just ensure the one column of interest is processed the right way –  if each entry is already a Python list-of-strings, you're fine, but if it's a string, you might have to break into a list-of-tokens.

When you're doing it right, you'll only pass the entire corpus's iterable into the `Word2Vec` class once - it will then read it, over the many passes required for training, as it needs it by requesting repeated iterations. (It has no idea where the data is coming from, or how your iterable is implemented. It just knows it's got an object that it can request an iterator from, and that iterator gives it one of the right kind of item each `next()`, until reaching the end of one iteration.)

Comment: Thanks @gojomo! This is useful. So do you think this would work correctly?


```class MyCorpus:
    def __init__(self, corpus):
        self.data = pq.ParquetFile('/mybigparquet.pq')

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in self.data.iter_batches(batch_size=1):
            yield line.tokens```

Comment: What happens when you try it, for example in a test loop that just prints each next item?

Comment: it does seem to work... but is suuuuper slow. i wonder if somehow `gensim` can train a word2vec model in batches instead of one row at a time? I was not able to figure this out from the documentation

Comment: What do you mean by 'suuuuper slow' in terms of observed rates? Is that compared to something else, such as a purely-local run? What made you choose 40 worker threads (which is likely to be far from optimal in corpus-iterator mode, but might work well in an alternate `corpus_file` mode that's only valid when training from a single local file)? If things are now working, but just slower than desired, that sounds like a new question, which could be asked with the full details of what you've tried, what rates have been observed, & what your hopes are of faster performance.